# Why does the runtime of Qiskit's job.result() scale with the number of shots?

Tags: qiskit, programming

I have a list of transpiled circuits that I run on `Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator')`.

```
qobj = assemble([mapped_circuit.bind_parameters(dict(zip(all_qiskit_params, all_param_values[:, pp])))
                         for pp in range(n_reps)], backend=backend, shots=N_shots)
job = backend.run(qobj)
counts = job.result().get_counts()
```

Depending on the `N_shots` the runtime is slower; I am okay with it, but by looking more closely I found that what really takes a long time is the call of `job.result()`, which goes to less than 1 sec for `N_shots = 1e4`, 8 secs for `N_shots = 1e5`to over a minute for `N_shots = 1e6`.

Is this expected or there is a faster way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`backend.run` submits the job, but `job.result` will wait for the outcome. So if you run a more expensive calculations, like sampling more shots, you will see more time spent in `job.result`.